esp32s3 lora + bme280 sensor
Im using t3s3 esp32s3 lora module and i have question can i solder dirrectly bme280 sensor and then redefine code or should i wire them separately on. And how should i know which pins are scl and sda on board, because i cant see them physically.This is pinout of board https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0617/7190/7253/files/T3-S3.jpg?v=1723193738 and this is sensor https://iotdesignpro.com/sites/default/files/inline-images/BME280-Pinout.jpg

The BME280 supports I2C or SPI communication, and the picture of the linked BME280 module appears to show all pins required for SPI communication are present. The pin labels for the ESP32S3 LORA board appear to show SPI signals. Is it possible for you to use SPI rather than I2C communication between the two boards?

Yes, it is possible, but my mailny problem is i dont quite understand what are pins for sda, scl,cs, sdo on board(on what pins should i wire them). I understand they are defined like scl(17) and sda(18), but i dont understand how to wire them,on what gpio(for example I045). And if i could solder them dirrectly on board and then redefine them in code. Thank you for answering
